# Particle Hole Transformation of Hamiltonian

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, operators

The particle hole transformation for a bipartite lattice $\Lambda$ (with sublattices $A$ and $B$) can be written as $$U^\dagger c_{i,\uparrow} U = \epsilon(i) c^\dagger_{i\uparrow} \\ U^\dagger c_{i,\downarrow} U = \epsilon(i) c^\dagger_{i\downarrow}$$
The factor $\epsilon(i)$ is $+1$ for the lattice index $i\in A$ and $-1$ for $i \in B$. The $c$ operators are the usual creation and annihilation operators for electrons. 
Now, if I have a Hamiltonian which has a term like $$H_s = \kappa \sum_i (n_{i,\uparrow} - n_{i,\downarrow})$$ 
how do I know how this transforms? My guess was that I only have to substitute all the $c_{i\downarrow}$ with $c^\dagger_{i\downarrow}$ and all the $c_{i\uparrow}$ with $c^\dagger_{i\uparrow}$ (and vice versa). This would give me an overall minus sign in this part of the Hamiltonian, so that $$H_s' = -\kappa \sum_i (n_{i,\uparrow} - n_{i,\downarrow})$$ 
However, [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184773/particle-hole-symmetry-of-single-site?rq=1) made be believe that I also have to flip the spins, so that $c_{i\downarrow} \rightarrow c^\dagger_{i\uparrow}$, $c_{i\uparrow} \rightarrow c^\dagger_{i\downarrow}$, $c^\dagger_{i\downarrow} \rightarrow c_{i\uparrow}$ and $c^\dagger_{i\uparrow} \rightarrow c_{i\downarrow}$.

Comment: The Hamiltonian $H_s$ you considered is not particle-hole symmetric, that is why it is not invariant under the transformation. You need to redefine the particle-hole transformation with spin flipping in order to make the transformation a symmetry of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Is there more than one particle-hole transformation and why am I allowed to just define one with spin flip? Is this still a unitary transformation?

Comment: There are infinitely many particle-hole transformations, all related by unitary transforms. Each particle-hole transformation followed by a nontrivial unitary transform is another particle-hole. Now spin flip itself is a unitary transform. Because a unitary transform followed by another unitary transform will still be unitary, spin flip does not change the unitary nature of particle-hole transform.