# What's the reason for particle-hole symmetry operator to be anti-unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-insulators

I have been looking at some literature on Topological Superconductor, where the BdG Hamiltonian is frequently used, the $H_{BdG}$ has the so-called particle-hole symmetry, which is commonly defined through $C=\sigma_x \mathcal{K}$, where $C^{-1}HC=-H^*$.

As a beginner, I'm really curious about the basic definition of this particle-hole "transformation".Why should it be defined like this? Hope someone can answer this question.

Comment: It has to transform the charge to the opposite, and this comes as the covariant derivative $\partial-ieA$, so it has to deal with the complex conjugation (see e.g. the book by Itzykson and Zuber). Now, the operation which contains the complex conjugation and commutes with the Hamiltonian is called the time-reversal operation. The one which anti-commutes is the charge conjugation, or particle-hole symmetry. Its exact definition is up to you, the important thing is that it's the symmetry which anti-commutes and contains a complex conjugation operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Particle-hole symmetry is only antilinear in the one-particle space. It is *linear* and *unitary* when acting on the many-particle Fock space. See footnote after eq 4 in  S.Ryu, A.Schnyder, A.Furusaki, A.Ludwig, *Topological insulators and superconductors: ten-fold way and dimensional hierarchy*  New J. Phys. 12, 065010 (2010). ArXiv:0912.2157.

Supose that the one particle Hamiltonian has the property that
$$
C H^* C^{-1}= -H
$$
for some unitary matrix $C$. Then
$$
Hu_n=\lambda_n u_n\quad\Rightarrow \quad HCu_n^* = -\lambda_n Cu^*_n,
$$
so, when $\lambda$ is non zero, the single-particle eigenfunctions come in opposite-eigenvalue  pairs.     In the absence of zero energy states the ground state $|0\rangle$ has all negative-energy states occupied and   is non-degenerate.

We define the action of a  *unitary* particle-hole operator ${\mathsf C}$ on the many-body Fock space by
$$
{\mathsf C}\Psi_\beta {\mathsf C}^{-1}= \Psi_\alpha^\dagger C_{\alpha\beta}, \quad {\mathsf C}\Psi^\dagger_\beta {\mathsf C}^{-1}= C^\dagger_{\beta\alpha}\Psi_\alpha.
$$

When
${\mathsf C}$ acts on the Hamiltonian  we have
$$ 
{\mathsf C}\hat H {\mathsf C}^{-1}=
{\mathsf C}\Psi^\dagger_\alpha H_{\alpha\beta} \Psi_\beta {\mathsf C}^{-1}\\
={\mathsf C}\Psi^\dagger_\alpha {\mathsf C}^{-1}{\mathsf C}H_{\alpha\beta}{\mathsf C}^{-1}{\mathsf C}  \Psi_\beta {\mathsf C}^{-1}\\
= {\mathsf C}\Psi^\dagger_\alpha {\mathsf C}^{-1}H_{\alpha\beta}{\mathsf C} \Psi_\beta {\mathsf C}^{-1}\\
= C^\dagger_{\alpha\rho}\Psi_{\rho}  H_{\alpha\beta} \Psi^\dagger_\sigma C_{\sigma\beta}\\
=- \Psi^\dagger_\sigma C_{\sigma\beta} H_{\alpha\beta}C^\dagger_{\alpha\rho}\Psi_{\rho}\\
=- \Psi^\dagger_\sigma C_{\sigma\beta} H^T_{\beta \alpha}C^\dagger_{\alpha\rho}\Psi_{\rho}\nonumber\\
=- \Psi^\dagger_\sigma C_{\sigma\beta} H^*_{\beta \alpha}C^\dagger_{\alpha\rho}\Psi_{\rho}\nonumber\\
=+ \Psi^\dagger_\sigma H_{\sigma\rho} \Psi_{\rho}.\\
= \hat H.
$$
So the one-particle transformation on $H$ leaves the many-particle hamiltonian invariant.

Note: In expressions like $ \Psi^\dagger_\sigma C_{\sigma\beta} H_{\alpha\beta}C^\dagger_{\alpha\rho}\Psi_{\rho}$, the quantities $\Psi^\dagger_\sigma$ and $\Psi_{\rho}$ are second quantized operators, whereas $C_{\sigma\beta}$ or $H_{\alpha\beta}$ are regular complex numbers (they are the components of the relevant matrices).

Note that we have used $C^{*\dagger} = C^T$ and the tracelessness (line 5 $\to$ 6) and hermiticity of $H$ in the above manipulations.
More importantly, and   despite the appearance of ``$*$" in the action  on $H$, the many-body operator  ${\mathsf C}$ must act  on the Fock space  *linearly*:
$$
{\mathsf C}(\lambda |\psi_1\rangle+\mu |\psi_2\rangle)= \lambda {\mathsf C}|\psi_1\rangle+\mu {\mathsf C}|\psi_2\rangle.
$$
The linearity is  required  in the step
$$
{\mathsf C}H_{\alpha\beta}{\mathsf C}^{-1}= H_{\alpha\beta}.
$$

Comment: I think the line 4 to line 5 in your main deduction is to exchange $\psi^\dagger_\sigma$ and $\psi_\rho$. But why does this exchange not produce the $\delta_{\sigma,\rho}$ term, as $\{\psi_\alpha,\psi_\beta^\dagger\}=\delta_{\alpha,\beta}$?

Comment: @Jason. The matrix $H$ is traceless. That follows from hermiticity and $CH^*C^{-1}=-H$. As a consequence, the contributions from the $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$'s  sum  to zero.

Comment: Oh, I see! One more question. Why $\mathrm{C}\Psi^\dagger_\beta\mathrm{C}^{-1}=C_{\beta\alpha}^\dagger\Psi_\alpha$ but not $\mathrm{C}\Psi_\beta^\dagger\mathrm{C}^{-1}=\Psi_\beta$? I mean, from the general definition, they should be as the later form.

Comment: @Jason The second equation (with the $C^\dagger$) follows from the first by taking its Hermitian conjugate.

Comment: I know that. What I am confused about is that why the form of particle hole symmetry is not just change the creation operator into the annihilation operator of the same quantum   number(as eq.(1) in the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184773/particle-hole-symmetry-of-single-site)), but a linear combination of annihilation operators as above and in the paper mensioned? If so, how can I determine the coefficient $C_{\alpha\beta}$ in the definition?

Comment: @Jason. Sorry I misunderstood your question. Usually  you need the $C$ matrix to take care of  the spin degree of freedom. The spin-1/2 of ${\rm SU}(2)$ is a pseudo-real representation i.e equivalent to its conjugate, yetnot a *real* representation.  Often $C=i\sigma_2$ as this  transforms a spin  to its complex conjugate.

Comment: I think it's getting closer to the final answer. Why does the reality of representation matters? Is it true that if the representation under bases of $\Psi^\dagger_\alpha$ is real, we could simply have $\mathrm{C}\Psi_\alpha^\dagger\mathrm{C}^{-1}=\Psi_\alpha$? Is there a systematic method to deduce the represention of particle-hole symmetry operator under arbitary bases?

Comment: Well, maybe my question is kind of hard to answer... Would you please give some more declaration about why the representation is $i\sigma_2$ when tackling spin? Or maybe some links about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jason. You need to look at the concrete examples in literature. See the review arXiv:0912.2157 and for relativistic systems  my arXiv:2009.00518 and

Answer (score 6):

I find it conceptually more simple to think of particle-hole symmetry as defined in second quantization notation. Indeed: the very meaning of a particle-hole transformation should mean that it should interchanging particles and holes, i.e. we want $\mathcal C c^\dagger \mathcal C = c$ (where $\mathcal C^2 = 1$). The anti-unitarity then follows from wanting $\mathcal C$ to preserve the $U(1)$ symmetry of fermions: if $c \to e^{i\alpha} c$, then $\mathcal C (e^{-i\alpha} c^\dagger )\mathcal C = e^{i\alpha} c$. I.e. we want that $\mathcal C e^{-i\alpha} \mathcal C = e^{i\alpha}$. This then naturally and completely defines the particle-hole transformation $\mathcal C$ !

Then how to define being invariant under this symmetry? Naively we would say $\mathcal C H \mathcal C = H$. However this is not the right notion. To see this, take the simple case of $H = \sum t_{ij} c_i^\dagger c_j + \mu c_i^\dagger c_i$. Intuitively we see that this should be particle-hole symmetric if $\mu = 0$. (To convince yourself, consider the case of nearest-neighbour hopping, in which case we know the spectrum is just a cosine, which is clearly particle-hole symmetric at half-filling, i.e. $\mu = 0$.) Using our above definition, $\mathcal C H\mathcal C = \sum t_{ij}^* c_i c_j^\dagger + \mu c_i c_i^\dagger$, which by the fermionic commutation rules is the same as $- \sum \left( t_{ji}^* c_i^\dagger c_j + \mu c_i^\dagger c_i \right) + \mu N_\textrm{sites}$. Then again by the fact that $H$ must be Hermitian, we know that $t_{ji}^* = t_{ij}$, so we see that
$$ \mathcal C H\mathcal C = -H + \mu N_\textrm{sites}$$

I.e. in the particle-hole symmetric case, we have that $ \mathcal C H\mathcal C = -H$. It is then natural to take this as our *definition* of particle-hole symmetry!

Comment: thanks.
As for the example, you are absolutely right, but I think it's better to express the Hamiltonian as $H=\frac{1}{2} \sum t_{i,j} (c^{\dagger}_i c_j-c_j c^{\dagger}_i)＋\mu (c^{\dagger}_i c_i - c_i c^{\dagger}_i )+ const$, which is in the particle-hole basis.

Comment: Nice explanation! But it seems to me the statement that $\mathcal{C}$ preserves the U(1) symmetry of fermions contradicts the fact that $\mathcal{C}$ is unitary in second quantization form (as pointed out in mike stone's answer). Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

A more fundamental answer to why the particle-hole operator is taken that way is to look towards QFT. There we have particles and antiparticles and we can assign a charge of $+q$ to a particle and $-q$ to the antiparticle. Thus a operator that interchanges particles and antiparticles $\mathcal{C}$  must satisfy $\mathcal{C}|p\rangle=|\bar{p}\rangle$ so if we have a charge operator $\mathcal{Q}$ it must satisfy: $\mathcal{Q}|p\rangle=q|p\rangle$ and $\mathcal{Q}|\bar{p}\rangle=-q|\bar{p}\rangle$. Now we apply the $\mathcal{C}$ operator:

$$\mathcal{C} \mathcal{Q}|p\rangle= \mathcal{C} q|p\rangle= q|\bar{p}\rangle$$
While simultaneously:
$$\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{C}|p\rangle= \mathcal{Q}|\bar{p}\rangle= -q|\bar{p}\rangle$$
Thus we must have
$$\mathcal{Q}\mathcal{C}=-\mathcal{C} \mathcal{Q}$$
In this sense if an operator is consistent with how charges change under  $\mathcal{C}$  then:
$$\mathcal{C}^{-1}\mathcal{A}\mathcal{C}=-\mathcal{A}$$
Now this we can apply to the Hamiltonian , note that we can't have $\mathcal{H}\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{C} \mathcal{H}$ since this would imply simultaneous eigenstates of the Hamiltonian and $\mathcal{C}$, but the only eigenstates of $\mathcal{C}$ are particles whose antiparticle is themselves since $\mathcal{C}^2=1$. So to establish consistency of particles and antiparticles the Hamiltonian must satisfy:
$$\mathcal{C}\mathcal{H}\mathcal{C}=-\mathcal{H}$$
This actually links to the above answer since maintaining $U(1)$ symmetry implies charge conservation so $\mathcal{C}$ must be anti-unitary. For the case of Condensed Matter we take, conveniently, holes to be the antiparticle of electrons since clearly they have opposite charge. Then all of the above follows.