# How particle-hole transformation act on momentum?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry

1. In Everett You's answer to [Particle hole symmetry of single site?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184773/particle-hole-symmetry-of-single-site) he explains how particle-hole transformation acts on a single site. **But, we know that the operation of particle-hole transformation $\mathcal{P}$ reverses momentum and spin but leaves position invariant.** From equation $\mathcal{P}c^\dagger_{i\sigma}\mathcal{P}^{-1}=c_{i\sigma}$, one can obtain that 
   $$\mathcal{P}c^\dagger_{k\sigma}\mathcal{P}^{-1}=c_{k\sigma}$$ using Fourier transformation. Furthermore, one can obtain 
   $$\mathcal{P}c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}|0\rangle=c^\dagger_{k\downarrow}|0\rangle.$$
   Thus,  a state with momentum $k$ and spin up $c^\dagger_{k\uparrow}|0\rangle$ transforms into a state  $c^\dagger_{k\downarrow}|0\rangle$ with momentum $k$ and spin-down. **Under the particle-hole transformation, the momentum of state does not reverse.**  I am confused by this contradiction. How can I solve this problem?
2. How can I prove the transformation of a Bloch Hamiltonian under the particle-hole reversal $\mathcal{P}$?
   $$\mathcal{P}h(-k)\mathcal{P}^{-1}=-h(k),$$
   where $h(k)$ is a Bloch Hamiltonian.

Comment: Particle-hole transformation is antiunitary, so there is a complex conjugation in it.